# How can I make the Y axis of a subplot synchronize but keep their labels separated?

Tags: plotly-python

In plotly if you have this script

```
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go
    
fig = make_subplots(
    rows=1, cols=2, subplot_titles=("Plot 1", "Plot 2")
)

# Add traces
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[1, 2, 3], y=[4, 5, 6]), row=1, col=1)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[20, 30, 40], y=[50, 60, 70]), row=1, col=2)


# Update xaxis properties
fig.update_xaxes(title_text="xaxis 1 title", row=1, col=1)
fig.update_xaxes(title_text="xaxis 2 title", range=[10, 50])


# Update yaxis properties
fig.update_yaxes(title_text="yaxis 1 title", row=1, col=1)
fig.update_yaxes(title_text="yaxis 2 title",  row=1, col=2, overlaying='y', side='right')


# Update title and height
fig.update_layout(title_text="Customizing Subplot Axes", height=700)

fig.show()
```

You get
[image]

Very nice!
Except that both plots are not synchronized.

So if we change the `make_subplots` to

```
fig = make_subplots(
    rows=1, cols=2, subplot_titles=("Plot 1", "Plot 2"),shared_yaxes=True
)
```

We get

[image]

Now if you zoom one, you zoom in the other too. Even nicer!

But, now the "yaxis 2 title" appears to the left of the whole plot!

How can we put this back to the left of the second subplot?